# Check if any of a list of strings is in another string

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

In python, I'm trying to create a program which checks if 'numbers' are in a string, but I seem to get an error. Here's my code:

```
numbers = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0"]

test = input()

print(test)
if numbers in test:
    print("numbers")
```

Here's my error:

```
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not list
```

I tried changing numbers into `numbers = "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0"` which is basically removed the `[]` but this didn't work either. Hope I can get an answer; thanks :)

Comment: What do you want to know ? If every number is in the list ? Or which ones are in it ?

Comment: I want to know if any of the numbers are in the string.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use built-in [***any()***](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) function:

```
numbers = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0"]
s = input()

test = any(n in s for n in numbers)
print(test)
```

Answer (score 3):

In a nutshell, you need to check each digit individually.

There are many ways to do this:

For example, you could achieve this using a loop (left as an exercise), or by using sets

```
if set(test) & set(numbers):
  ...
```

or by making use of `str.isdigit`:

```
if any(map(str.isdigit, test)):
  ...
```

(Note that both examples assume that you're testing for digits, and don't readily generalize to arbitrary substrings.)

Answer (score 1):

Other possible way may be to iterate through each character and check if it is numeric using `isnumeric()` method:

```
input_string = input()

# to get list of numbers
num_list = [ch for ch in input_string if ch.isnumeric()]
print (num_list)

# can use to compare with length to see if it contains any number
print(len(num_list)>0)
```

If `input_string = 'abc123'` then, `num_list` will store all the numbers in `input_string` i.e. `['1', '2', '3']` and `len(num_list)>0` results in `True`.

Answer (score 0):

As NPE said, you have to check every single digit. The way i did this is with a simple for loop.

```
for i in numbers:
    if i in test:
        print ("test")
```

Hope this helped :)